# Get keys (objects) from a dictionary that contains list and filtered by values

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return the list of keys (type A) that contains an object of type B. The type B object has a property that will be used to be compared, and I can not use the Contains.
I am trying to do get a list of A

```
Dictionary<A, List<B>> objAwithB = new Dictionary<A, List<B>>();
B objB = new B();
objB.prop1 = "AAA"
objAwithB.Where(g => g.Value.Where(a=>a.Equals(objB.prop1))).Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
var myKeys = objAwithB.Where(
    kvp => kvp.Value.Any(v => v.prop1.Equals(objB.prop1) )
  ).Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want:

```
objAwithB.Where(g => g.Value.Any(b=>b.prop1.Equals(objB.prop1)))
         .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any() should do the trick:

```
Dictionary<A, List<B>> objAwithB = new Dictionary<A, List<B>>();
B objB = new B();
objB.Prop1 = "AAA";

objAwithB.Where(g => g.Value.Any(x => x.Prop1 == objB.Prop1))
         .Select(g => g.Key)
         .ToList();
```